# Using mencoder to convert videos for your mobile phone

Tags: video, conversion, mobile-phone, mencoder

I Have a LG Viewty (actually a KP501), and I use *mencoder* (part of *mplayer*) to convert videos, using the following script :

```
mencoder "input.avi" -ovc lavc -oac lavc -lavcopts acodec=mp3:abitrate=128 -vop scale=400:240 -ffourcc DX50 -o "output.avi"
```

Do you have similar mencoder scripts, for other phones ?

Comment: I started this question as a way to centralize mencoder commands

Comment: I'll leave the question open a little while, if someone else has a mencoder script to share.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For iPhone I used this before with success:

```
mencoder "$file" -subcp cp1252 -sub-fuzziness 1 -subfont-autoscale 3 -subfont-blur 2 -subfont-outline 2 -aid 1 -vf scale=480:320:0:0:0.00:0.50,dsize=480:320,harddup -sws 2 -of lavf -lavfopts format=mp4 -ovc x264 -x264encopts bitrate=768:qcomp=0.6:qp_min=10:qp_max=51:qp_step=4:vbv_maxrate=1500:vbv_bufsize=2000:level_idc=30:dct_decimate:me=umh:me_range=16:keyint=250:keyint_min=25:nofast_pskip:global_header:nocabac:direct_pred=auto:nomixed_refs:trellis=1:nobrdo:nobime:nob_pyramid:nob_adapt:no8x8dct:noweight_b:bframes=0:threads=auto:frameref=1:subq=6 -af channels=2 -oac faac -faacopts br=128:mpeg=4:object=2:tns:raw -o /converted_"$file" .m4v
```