# Batch convert divx to iPhone format

Tags: video, iphone, conversion, batch, ipod-touch

I am looking for **free** software to do batch conversions of divx video files to iPhone format.

I have read the thread:

https://superuser.com/questions/5784/looking-to-convert-video-to-iphone-format

Handbrake works good for single files but it has very little customization with regards to files names and the batch functionality is not very good (or at least I can't get it to work very easily).

Can anyone recommend a good batch converter?  A script for Handbrake to do a batch for all in a specific directory would be useful even.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[winff](http://winff.org/html_new/) would do - its a nice little front end for ffmpeg, and works on windows and linux. It also gives you the ffmpeg commands should you want to do it in command line.

Comment: Links please :)

Comment: i edited it with a link a couple of minutes after my initial post 
http://winff.org would be what you want

Answer (score 4):

Handbrake is easily automated by creating a batch script using [HandBrake CLI](http://trac.handbrake.fr/wiki/CLIGuide) (see the links found at the end, or just simply [google](http://www.google.fr/#hl=en&safe=off&num=30&q=handbrake+batch+conversion&fp=6f03a58a35778b03) for many examples).

Answer (score 1):

Besides [Handbrake](http://handbrake.fr/), there is also [XVID4PSP](http://www.winnydows.com/page.php?2) to check.
If the first one works for you, stick to it.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps videora can help you? [Videora](http://www.videora.com/). If you are on a Mac try using [ReduxEncoder](http://blog.easelnet.net/).

Answer (score 0):

I did a script in order to do what you are trying to do, but for a different kind of phone.

I used *mencoder*, which is a part of *Mplayer* ([link](http://www.mplayerhq.hu)). It has the advantages of being free, and able to play nearly anything you throw at it.

You should check out [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/15219/using-mencoder-to-convert-videos-for-your-mobile-phone), I created it in order to centralize mencoder commands.

Here's the command for my phone :

> mencoder "input.avi" -ovc lavc -oac
>   lavc -lavcopts acodec=mp3:abitrate=128
>   -vop scale=400:240 -ffourcc DX50 -o "output.avi"

Someone else mentionned this command for iphones, but I haven't tested it :

> mencoder "$file" -subcp cp1252
>   -sub-fuzziness 1 -subfont-autoscale 3 -subfont-blur 2 -subfont-outline 2 -aid 1 -vf scale=480:320:0:0:0.00:0.50,dsize=480:320,harddup
>   -sws 2 -of lavf -lavfopts format=mp4 -ovc x264 -x264encopts bitrate=768:qcomp=0.6:qp_min=10:qp_max=51:qp_step=4:vbv_maxrate=1500:vbv_bufsize=2000:level_idc=30:dct_decimate:me=umh:me_range=16:keyint=250:keyint_min=25:nofast_pskip:global_header:nocabac:direct_pred=auto:nomixed_refs:trellis=1:nobrdo:nobime:nob_pyramid:nob_adapt:no8x8dct:noweight_b:bframes=0:threads=auto:frameref=1:subq=6
>   -af channels=2 -oac faac -faacopts br=128:mpeg=4:object=2:tns:raw -o
>   /converted_"$file" .m4v

Once you have found the mplayer commands that work well with your phone, you can add them in a python script, allowing you to batch convert lots of files :

[Stack Overflow : Using Python to execute a command on every file in a folder.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120707/using-python-to-execute-a-command-on-every-file-in-a-folder)