# Encode divx into iPhone-compatible MPEG4 while downloading?

Tags: video, iphone, streaming, encoding, mpeg4

Is there a way to encode a DivX file into an iPhone-compatible video file while the DivX is downloading/streaming?

Further, is it possible to re-stream the resulting iPhone-compatible video to the iPhone with a minimal (say, 2 minute or so) delay?

I've seen [other questions](https://superuser.com/questions/5784/looking-to-convert-video-to-iphone-format) [about encoding](https://superuser.com/questions/15219/using-mencoder-to-convert-videos-for-your-mobile-phone) [iPhone-compatible videos](https://superuser.com/questions/40368/batch-convert-divx-to-iphone-format) but they don't quite address the streaming video source and potential of streaming output that I'm interested in.

Comment: Jonathan, your original question read like converting on the fly is a "nice-to-have", not required, feature, and the while-downloading requirement was hard to spot.  i've edited the post so both of these points are more obvious.  hopefully the edit doesn't misrepresent your intentions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buzz player app works in this scenario exactly. (however at the time of asking it was not around)
The folder the video is in must be shared on the network